# Calculating start of day and start of month in UTC

Tags: c#, timezone

I have users that can be in different timezones and I'm looking to determine the UTC value of the beginning of their days and their months. Inside an object, I have a method that attempts to do that; it looks like this:

```
private void SetUserStartTimesUTC()
{
    DateTime TheNow = DateTime.UtcNow.ConvertUTCTimeToUserTime(this.UserTimezoneID);

    DateTime TheUserStartDateUserTime = TheNow.Date;
    DateTime TheUserStartMonthUserTime = new DateTime(TheNow.Year, TheNow.Month, 1);
    DateTime TheUserEndMonthUserTime = TheUserStartMonthUserTime.AddMonths(1);

    this.UserStartOfDayUTC = TheUserStartDateUserTime.ConvertUserTimeToUTCTime(this.UserTimezoneID);
    this.UserStartOfMonthUTC = TheUserStartMonthUserTime.ConvertUserTimeToUTCTime(this.UserTimezoneID);
    this.UserEndOfMonthUTC = TheUserEndMonthUserTime.ConvertUserTimeToUTCTime(this.UserTimezoneID);
}
```

And this method depends on two other extension methods that do the conversions between a user's time and UTC time

```
public static DateTime ConvertUserTimeToUTCTime(this DateTime TheUserTime, string TheTimezoneID)
{
    TimeZoneInfo TheTZ = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TheTimezoneID);
    DateTime TheUTCTime = new DateTime();

    if (TheTZ != null)
    {
        DateTime UserTime = new DateTime(TheUserTime.Year, TheUserTime.Month, TheUserTime.Day, TheUserTime.Hour, TheUserTime.Minute, TheUserTime.Second);
        TheUTCTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(UserTime, TheTZ);
    }

    return TheUTCTime;
}

public static DateTime ConvertUTCTimeToUserTime(this DateTime TheUTCTime, string TheTimezoneID)
{
    TimeZoneInfo TheTZ = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TheTimezoneID);
    DateTime TheUserTime = new DateTime();

    if (TheTZ != null)
    {
        DateTime UTCTime = new DateTime(TheUTCTime.Year, TheUTCTime.Month, TheUTCTime.Day, TheUTCTime.Hour, TheUTCTime.Minute, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        TheUserTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(UTCTime, TheTZ);
    }

    return TheUserTime;
}
```

Now I've been dealing with timezone issues for a while and I know that timezone issues can introduce off-by-one bugs that can be hard to detect.

Does my implementation of timezones seem to be correct or is there an edge case that will create some sort of off-by-one bug?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Why are you using Pascal-cased *local* variable names and prefixing them all with `The`? `TheNow` is a bizarre name, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet: in my code, I use variables that start with The to indicate that I'm dealing with an instance. It's just a habit I picked up.

Comment: What else would you be dealing with? Note that `DateTime` is a value type, so if it's meant to indicate that there's an *object* involved, your code is contravening your own conventions, along with the widely used .NET conventions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your methods seem needlessly complicated, to be honest.

Why would you have a parameter called `TheUTCTime` and then create a UTC version of it? Shouldn't it *already* have a `Kind` of UTC? Even if it didn't, you would be better off using `DateTime.SpecifyKind` - currently when converting one way you wipe out the seconds, whereas converting the other way you don't... in both cases you wipe out any sub-second values.

Also:

- `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` never returns `null`
- Returning `new DateTime()` (i.e. January 1st 0001 AD) if the time zone can't be found seems like a really poor way of indicating an error
- There's no need to have a local variable in your conversion methods; just return the result of calling `ConvertTime` directly
- Your "end of month" is really "start of the next month"; that may be what you want, but it's not clear.

Personally I would strongly advise you to avoid the BCL `DateTime` for all of this entirely. I'm entirely biased being the main author, but I'd at least hope that you'd find [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) more pleasant to work with... it separates out the idea of "date with no time component", "time with no date component", "local date and time with no specific time zone" and "date and time in a particular time zone"... so the type system helps you to only do sensible things.

EDIT: If you really *have* to do this within the BCL types, I'd write it like this:

```
private void SetUserStartTimesUTC()
{
    DateTime nowUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(UserTimeZoneID);

    // User-local values, all with a Kind of Unspecified.
    DateTime now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(nowUtc, zone);
    DateTime today = now.Date;
    DateTime startOfThisMonth = todayUser.AddDays(1 - today.Day);
    DateTime startOfNextMonth = startOfThisMonth.AddMonths(1);

    // Now convert back to UTC... see note below
    UserStartOfDayUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(today, zone);
    UserStartOfMonthUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(startOfThisMonth, zone);
    UserEndOfMonthUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(startOfNextMonth, zone);
}
```

The extension methods you've added really don't provide much benefit, as you can see.

Now, the code mentions a "note" - you're currently always *assuming* that midnight always exists and is unambiguous. That's not true in all time zones. For example, in Brazil, on daylight saving changes forward, the time skips from midnight to 1am - so midnight itself is invalid, basically.

In Noda Time we fix this by having `DateTimeZone.AtStartOfDay(LocalDate)` but it's not as easy with the BCL.

For comparison, the equivalent Noda Time code would look like this:

```
private void SetUserStartTimesUTC()
{
    // clock would be a dependency; you *could* use SystemClock.Instance.Now,
    // but the code would be much more testable if you injected it.
    Instant now = clock.Now;

    // You can choose to use TZDB or the BCL time zones
    DateTimeZone zone = zoneProvider.FindSystemTimeZoneById(UserTimeZoneID);

    LocalDateTime userLocalNow = now.InZone(zone);

    LocalDate today = userLocalNow.Date;
    LocalDate startOfThisMonth = today.PlusDays(1 - today.Day);
    LocalDate startOfNextMonth = startOfThisMonth.PlusMonths(1);

    UserStartOfDayUTC = zone.AtStartOfDay(today);
    UserStartOfMonthUTC = zone.AtStartOfDay(startOfThisMonth);
    UserEndOfMonthUTC = zone.AtStartOfDay(startOfNextMonth);
}
```

... where the properties would be of type `ZonedDateTime` (which remembers the time zone). You could change them to be of type `Instant` (which is just a point in time) if you want, just chaining a `ToInstant` call for each property setter.

Comment: Can you help me fix my code? That'd be really really helpful. I started learning to code 3 years ago on my own, with just books and online tutorials, so my C# skills aren't quite where I'd like them to be but I hope I'm getting there. I'd rather avoid creating dependencies. This part of the code is rather critical.

Comment: @frenchie: If this is critical code, why would you want to do the work yourself rather than trusting a library whose sole *job* is to do date and time work?

Comment: Because I find it harder to understand libraries than to create a few lines of my own code that I fully understand. I know it may not make all the sense in the world but that's how I've been coding.

Comment: @frenchie: I would contend that you *don't* actually fully understand your own code - otherwise you wouldn't be checking whether `FindSystemTimeZoneById` returned `null`, for example.

Comment: @frenchie: (And in general, I would *strongly* encourage you to avoid a "not invented here" syndrome. You'll find yourself reinventing a lot of wheels if you're unwilling to learn about anyone else's code.)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. Keep in mind that I'm biz/sales guy and I decided to learn tech just a few years ago. Just a quick question: what does BCL mean?

Comment: @frenchie: Base Class Library. Basically, what you get with .NET :) (That's a bit of a simplification, but close enough for this.)

Comment: Just noticed: "DateTime today = nowUser.Date;" did you mean to write DateTime today = now.Date; ?

Comment: @frenchie: Yes. I'd started off with a "User" suffix for all variables, but then felt a comment would be simpler.

Comment: PS: the reason I created an extension method to convert timezones it to avoid having to instantiate a new TimeZoneInfo in every part of the code where conversions happen.

Comment: @frenchie: But you're calling `FindSystemTimeZoneById` *every time you call the method*. So in your version of it, you're finding the time zone four time. In my version, I'm finding it once. In Noda Time, you'd potentially use `ZonedDateTime` which remembers the time zone anyway. You might want to consider adding a method of `GetTimeZone` which does the lookup using the `UserTimeZoneID` if that makes it easier.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean; my goal was to make sure the string passed in  is a valid time zone. I updated my code and it works. Many thanks Jon!